# A static analysis tool for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, static-analysis

I have a list of fields extracted from a C/C++ code base. I have to analyze the source files to check which fields are modified or used by which functions. The tool I used for fields extraction is Exuberant CTAGS which gives a list of fields and functions after analyzing a code file independently. Any ideas/suggestions are welcome, if there are any tools out there that can be used to achieve the functionality or if some built-in functionality of some development tool like Visual Studio can help.

Comment: I'm guessing you won't find tools based on ctags to do this, but you might be better served looking for things in the LLVM/clang ecosystem.

Comment: What do you mean, "files modified by functions"?

Comment: FIELDS, or variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I achieved it by writing a mini-parser which parses source files to provide a list of functions and all fields modified by them.

Comment: This is not a SR style answer.  OP is looking for something he can get, not something you have ih a directory on some machine you own.  The "accepted as best answer" is self-serving nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com), it can report you what you want and you can customize its cqlinq queries to query as you want the codebase.